# warning in macro that print a value

Tags: c, macros, warnings, gnu-make

I have the following macro

I want to print a variable name then the value,
so the macro will help having the variable name to show then its value

the result of my example show

`var = 1.234` printed on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define str(s) #s
#define PRINTER(X) printf("% 12s = % f\n", str(X), X);

int main()
{
   float var = 1.234f;
   PRINTER(var);// <===== warning here
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

my question, if you try it, let me know if you get a warning within main, and what it mean??
for me I get `` flag ` ' used with type `s' ``

**`edit:`**

**flag description**

(space) If no sign is going to be written, a blank space is inserted before the value.

Comment: Try removing the space between `%` and `12s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сhange

```
#define PRINTER(X) printf("% 12s = % f\n", str(X), X);
```

to

```
#define PRINTER(X) printf("%12s = %f\n", str(X), X);`
```

Notice the space removed between `%` and specifier.

Comment: the space is allowed with almost any type except string, I have a flag to adjust the printing location, and that's why I was trying it